# Why must the Amiga 1020 disk drive be powered-on before and powered-off after the Amiga computer?

Tags: hardware, amiga, amiga-1000, amiga-1020

The Amiga 1020 was a 5.25" disk drive for use with the Amiga computer. Anecdotally, I suspect they are somewhat rarer these days because they were a less popular choice for a second drive back in the late 1980's when the 'next big thing' was 3.5" disks.

A small 'flip' was provided with the drive entitled "Connecting the Amiga 5.25 External Disk Drive" that discusses the correct way to daisy chain and hook up the disk drive.  This flip repeatedly warns users in bold print about the dangers of turning the drive on or off 'out of order'.  For example,

On page 2, "**Note, The Amiga will not run unless you turn the disk drive on first.**"

On page 3, "**Warning: Do not turn off the 5.25 external disk drive while the Amiga is turned on.**"

On page 4, "**Note, Whenever it is connected, the 5.25 disk drive must be turned on first or the Amiga will not run.**"

There is also an entire page devoted to making sure the order of external drives is correct, which boils down to making sure the drives without an internal power supply (like an Amiga 1010) is always first in the chain and followed by one or two 'powered' A1020 drives.

This seems like a lot of dire warnings and quite a bit of detail; which makes me suspect that doing it wrong might cause 'bad things to happen' to my beloved Amiga 1000.

I can assume the Amiga 1010 should be first in the chain because it pulls power from the computer.  But if you exclude the A1010 and consider only of the A1020, I would like to better understand the risks of 'doing it wrong' without actually releasing any magic smoke.

Why would the Amiga fail to turn on without first turning on the A1020?  Why would turning off the A1020 before the Amiga cause a problem?  What is the risk to my hardware if I forget myself and just 'turn off' the A1020 while my Amiga is still running?

Comment: I can understand the potential *software* problem — Amiga drives are located and queried for type at startup, each being able to serialise a type identifier — but that wouldn’t explain all of the scare warnings above.

Comment: Possible boot hang condition? Maybe the Amiga can 'see' the drive because there's return current on a sense pin, so it expects the drive to answer the identification message and waits for the response - but then gets stuck in a waitloop because the drive initialised after the message was sent (thereby missing it, and never getting another because the Amiga is stuck)?

Comment: Have you got the schematics for the A1020 drive? I only found official servive notes for modifying it to work with an A500, and it only shows a partial schematics needed to describe the modification. Though, I could make some educated guesses based on it, but I'd rather be sure regarding the hardware. The other part is of course what the ROM boot code or loaded OS assumes about the state of hardware pins.

Comment: @Justme, I do not have any schematics.  I posted a separate question trying to figure if a proper manual ever existed (they sometimes had schematics in them) but I'm beginning to suspect there was no manual.  I did find the same A500 modification notes you describe, but nothing else.